# Restsharp, Youtube API and C# how to make them work together?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, youtube-api, restsharp

I know there is a google client library for uploading videos to youtube but i am doing a small experiment

```
var client = new RestClient()
{
   BaseUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet"

};     

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+ ytAccessToken);              
request.AddHeader("X-upload-content-length", size_of_video);
request.AddHeader("X-upload-content-type", "video/*");               
request.AddParameter("key", ClientID);
request.AddFile("videoFile", DownloadVideoAsByte(videoUrl), "newVideoFile");  
var result = client.Execute(request);
```

The good thing is that it creates a video in YouTube
the bad thing is it stuck in "processing" state

anyone who want to help me run this code ?